# Rails form validation appears on page load before submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright, I've got to be missing something simple.

I'm using a partial "/shared/_error_messages.html.erb" to handle

`<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>`

in my forms (one for adding programs, one for adding metrics).

When I navigate to any form (/programs/new and metrics/new), the validation appears when the page loads.

The programs_controller and metrics_controller are structurally the same (swapping @metrics for @programs in metrics_controller):

```
#programs_controller.rb
def new
  @programs = Program.new(params[:name])
  if @programs.save
    flash[:success] = "Program saved"
    redirect_to "/program"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

any ideas what might be causing this?

Here's the partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
     <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li>* <%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would prevent the `error_messages` partial from showing up ?

Comment: I thought that there would be no Object.errors until submit was pushed?

Comment: But then, where the code that check weither there is errors or not? Do you have `<% if object.errors.any? %>` at the top of your error partial?

Comment: I just added the partial code. It does contain the `<% if object.errors.any? %>` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the errors are but the problem is that your are saving your object in the `new` action. The saving generates the object errors; that is why you see them.

In a `RESTful` way, the new action should just instantiate a model and pass the object to your form. The form will submit it to the `create` action; where you should save your object and check errors.
Something like:

```
#programs_controller.rb
def new
  @programs = Program.new
end

def create
  @programs = Program.new(params[:program])
  if @programs.save
    # success
  else
    # failure
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, he is trying to save record on each 'new' action, validation runs and raise errors.